# lunarvim - javascript LS Inactive. How do I activate the language server for javascript?

Tags: lunarvim

Just installed lunarvim and testing the LSP feature.  if I create a python file, looks like "pyright" is used as the language server.  If I create a test javascript file like "test1.js", I see at the bottom right hand corner "LS Inactive".  Is there a way to activate the language server for javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Looks like LunarVim (and/or LSP) is looking for package.json.  Just created an empty package.json on the same directory and now LunarVim is using "tsserver".